# Cassandra and SQL Server replication

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, sqoop, talend, datastax

Im  looking for a way to replicate tables, possibly entire database from Microsoft SQL Server  to Cassandra (Datastax).  I don't need real time but can be around 30 second latency . So far research hasn't given me many good options.  I was looking at using Talend/Pentaho to schedule the jobs, possibly sqoop as well but then I still need an ETL tool to do some transformations before loading into Cassandra.

So I would like to pull data from SQL Server, perform some spark transformations on the data, then load into Cassandra.

So far  only real time replication I have seen involved flume plugin but to hdfs. cassandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want keep things simple, you can do the full job with DSE. You can schedule sqoop jobs with crontab mirroring data in cassandra, sqoop support incremental imports. Then you can schedule some spark job to perform etl and persist modified data in the final cassandra table.
If your data is big, you should perform ETL at scale with spark, don't use pentaho for that. IMHO

Comment: I'll look into this. One reason I was looking into Talend/Pentaho is because I can now schedule spark jobs from both. I figured using one of these tools would be easier from a monitoring and scheduling aspect as I could do it all from there. Versus setting up cron jobs and then have to set up all the alerting .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Talend Openstudio(Free) to get all the tables built as it was very easy with their replicate schema function to create the tabes in cassandra. Then I Have scheduled Spark Jobs that pull the data from SQL Server, perform our ETL, then import into DSE